# How to make the CSS of the navigation bar of my home site better in smaller widths

Tags: html, css

As evident from [this page on my home site](https://www.shlomifish.org/humour/bits/) when one shows the navbar on short widths, it obscures the text:

[image: firefox on linux screenshot]

It looks even worse in smartphones/etc.

I'm seeking a CSS fix as either a css fragment to copy+paste or a pull-req / patch for the sources on https://github.com/shlomif/shlomi-fish-homepage . I'm not using a css framework because i tried [materialize css](https://materializecss.com/) and it was too intrusive but i'm fine with using a different css framework.

( Note that [my site looks old fashioned by choice](https://www.shlomifish.org/meta/FAQ/#site_looks_old) and also unprofessional (with the "Back to my homepage" image and stuff) .)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. See: **[How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)**

Comment: In your main tag in your container all. You have your .sub-menu with a min-width of 220 px. That's why its getting weird on small screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your main tag in your `.container-all`. You have your .`sub-menu` with a min-width of 220 px. That's why its getting weird on small screen.

[image]

[image]

Maybe try to change your grid with media queries

EDITED

And also forget to mention the `position: absolute`

```
@media (max-width: 900px)
#navbar_wrapper {
background-color: #e0ebef;
/* position: absolute; */
```

}

[image]

Sure Dev Tool is your best friend !